# SQL Multiplication - Update Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL 2008 - Simple Query logic.

In my Table :TableName,  i have 3 columns [Ship Qty], Size, Qty.

Default value for Qty  is NULL. I wrote an Update Query to update the column : Qty. I need to multiply [Ship Qty] * Size.

Column : Size is nvarchar. It carries two conditons

1) If the value is 60 EA or 3 ML, I need to consider only 60 or 3 or 3.5 ...

2) If the value is 60X3 ML, I need to consider 60X3 which is 180. Then, this multiplied value will be multiplied with [Ship Qty].

```
update [TableName]
set Qty = [Ship Qty] * CONVERT(INT, (Size)) * CONVERT(Float, (Size))     
           WHERE  Size > 0         
           AND Size > 0         
           AND Qty IS NULL


Ship Qty    Size             Qty
1           100 EA           100
3           60 EA            180
2           60X3ML           360
```

In the above table, Column : Qty is updated through SQL Query. My Query throws exception.

Comment: WHAT exception? And is the quantity column called `Qty` or `[Ship Qty]`? And why are you multiplying by `Size` twice? And as Mat points out, what answer do you expect from 3 multiplied by 'EA'?

Comment: `Size > 0  AND Size > 0`? Converting `Size` both to Int and Float? When it's clearly not either in your sample?

Comment: Isn't `CONVERT(INT, (Size))` trying (and failing) to cast "EA" as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad/odd design but for what hopefully a one-off fix;

```
;with TEST ([Ship Qty], Size) as (
    select 1,'100 EA' union all
    select 3,'60 EA'  union all
    select 2,'60X3ML' union all
    select 2,'60X2ML' union all
    select 2,'60'     union all
    select 2,'1 X3PP'
)
select 
    [Ship Qty],
    Size,
    [Ship Qty] * (
            cast(substring(Size, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', Size + '/') - 1) as int)
            *
            case when charindex('X', Size, 1) > 0 then
                cast(substring(substring(Size, charindex('X', Size) + 1, len(Size)), 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(Size, charindex('X', Size) + 1, len(Size)) + '/') - 1) as int)
            else 
                1
            end
        )
from TEST
```

For

```
Ship Qty    Size    (No column name)
1           100 EA  100
3           60 EA   180
2           60X3ML  360
2           60X2ML  240
2           60      120
2           1 X3PP  6
```

Comment: thank you , Your syntax works. I need to remodify as per my table ..!!

Comment: i have a small correction on the above query. Query works well. But if it is 60X2.5ML, i am getting output as 120 and not as 150

Comment: i changed int to float, but i face the same issues

Comment: This is getting extremely fragile but replace line 16 of my example with `cast(substring(substring(Size, charindex('X', Size) + 1, len(Size)), 1, patindex('%[^0-9.]%', substring(Size, charindex('X', Size) + 1, len(Size)) + '/') - 1) as decimal(10, 5))`

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

- First: It seems to me that your multiplication may return a float and yet your QTY column looks like is defined as an integer
- Second (definitely an issue): You are converting the Size column, which has strings to a float. How do you expect that to work?
- Third: Why do you have two QTY columns in your example data? Where's the Ship QTY Column you refer to?

Comment: @lcarus, please check the values now .. i have edited the posting

Comment: In the Column:Size, i need to truncate the String Characters except letter X. If there is letter : X - I need to multiply ..!! For example, 60 X 3 is 180 !!

Comment: @Chok: I see your edit. My answer still holds. You are converting Size to float but the Size column contains non-digit characters! You can't do that!

Comment: @lcarus, thats my requirement .. as soon as i did, i will update you the query .. !! no issues !!

Comment: @Chok: this won't work. What's the volume for the first 2 rows? It says "EA"- (Each?) What's EA in that context? Liters, milliliters, Gallons?

Comment: @lcarus, We really dont want to worry about EA or ML or .. All we need to do is, if it is 60X3 ML .. We need to ignore ML and consider only 60X3, which is the product / multiplication output = 180. Later this value will be multiplied with [Ship Qty]

Comment: @Chok: This is almost an impossible task to do correctly. Look at the first 2 rows. They have "EA" separated by space after the quantity number. Look at the last one (60X3ML) how do you know where to stop parsing the string from left to right? When you see an M?, when you see a space? What if some else entered a "Y" after a number in a different row after the quantity number?  My advise: Tell your boss this is impossible unless they clean that Size column and since "EA" could mean anything, your calculation, even if possible, will always be flawed anyway. Forget about this.

Comment: @Chok: I see it. If you had something different than an "X" it won't work; and again, your calculations are flawed anyway without defining what EA mean? But there you go... use Alex's solution.